# Copy elements and parents in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>R1</th>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>R2</th>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>R3</th>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to copy all `th` and their parents (from `tr` up to `table`). The expected output should be:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>R1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>R2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>R3</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I'm copying everything except `td`'s.

I can do this in a step by step way (`table` first, then `thead`, so on and so forth). Is there a selector in jQuery that can do what I want in one line?

Answer (score 1):

I would *clone the entire `table`, then remove all the `td`s and append back it to `body`*.

```
var tab = $('table').clone();
tab.find('td').remove();
tab.appendTo('body');
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ93d/3/)

Comment: Did that, is there any more efficient way to do it?

Comment: @dpp I don't think there is better approach than this, anyway lets wait for other answers.